# Layout according to android version

Tags: android, alarm, android-2.3-gingerbread

i am trying to make a alarm clock, the GlowPadView in the newer android versions it quite good looking and i was planning to use that in my application, but at the same time i also want to support 2.3.3(Gingerbread) which still has a major chunk of phones. So i was wondering if there is a way that i can check the android version the phone is running and show the layout according to that. If the phone is running `API 11 +` the layout shows GlowPadView otherwise it shows basic swipe views from the Gingerbread stock alarm application.

To check the android version `Build.VERSION_CODES` can be used

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So i was wondering if there is a way that i can check the android version the phone is running and show the layout according to that.

Create separate directories, such as `res/layout/` and `res/layout-v11/`. Have the same-named layout resource in each (e.g., `foo.xml`), and put the `GlowPadView` in the `foo.xml` that you place in `res/layout-v11/`.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, you could just create two completely separate layouts, and then have an `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11)`, setContentView() to one layout and `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=11)` setContentView() to a different layout.

Comment: thanks for the answer i will try using this, hope it works. I thought i will have to make 2 projects which would have been quite difficult.